# Problemas con apollo client en react

Tags: reactjs, graphql

Hola estoy intentando consumir una query de graphql con apollo, pero el error que me trae es el siguiente:

> Error: "Network error: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."

cuando lo pruebo por el navegador a ese endpoint me funciona perfectamente. Ahora que pase a react e intento consumir desde la misma url me aparece ese error.

Mi configuracion en indes.js es:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

// 1
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo'
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'


// 2
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:3000/graphiql'
})

// 3
export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
})


ReactDOM.render(
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
    </ApolloProvider>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
// Learn more about service workers:
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

El componente que trae la querie por compose es:

```
        // React
    import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

    // React apollo
    import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
    import * as compose from 'lodash.flowright';

    // import queries
    import queries from './queries';

    // React bootstrap
    import { Container, Row, Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';



    class LoginForm extends React.Component {
        render() {

            const { posts } = this.props;
            console.log('que trae ', posts);
            return(
                <Fragment>
                <h1>hello</h1>
                </Fragment>
            );
        }
    }

    export default compose(
        graphql(queries.posts, { name: 'posts' }),
    )(LoginForm);
```

y para esa vista la querie es la siguiente:

```
    import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const queries = {
    posts: gql`
    query posts {
        title
    }
    `,
}

export default queries;
```

Answer (score 0):

Por fin el problema se ha resuelto, este consistia en que estaba apuntando el endpoint hacia el playground de graph => /graphiql y era /graphql:

```
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
 uri: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql'
})
```

Segundo Ademas de tener que instalar la gema cors -> [cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) y segundo seguir las instrucciones de instalacion para rails 5+

El tercer problema era que cuando consultaba la query la respuesta de esta era:

> ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken error

Por lo que tuve pille una respuesta satisfactoria en otro post en la que se debia setiar en applicationController la linea de **protect_from_forgery** de la siguiente manera:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  #protect_from_forgery with: :exception 
   protect_from_forgery prepend: true
end
```